# CSS columns and Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I made a simple container with "cards" presented in columns:

```
.card-container {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    -webkit-column-fill: auto;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    -moz-column-fill: auto;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 15px;
    column-fill: auto;
}

.card {
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
    column-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

This works perfectly in all other browsers (even IE :O ) except Firefox (incl dev version). I've tested in Chrome, Safari, Firefox, IE, and Edge.

Example: http://brianemilius.com

Halp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing '-moz-column-fill: auto' makes grid working properly. Hope it helps =)

Comment: oh I'd say the same thing you were quicker than me :'(

Comment: Yup, this worked! Do you have any explanation as to why the `-moz-column-fill` messes it up?